# Select2 4.0 multiple select box & placeholder displays blank item with selections

Tags: jquery-select2-4

I want to show a multiple select box that uses a placeholder (nothing unusual). I've prepended a blank item to the list, which enables the placeholder to be displayed, as expected.

```
<select id="county_id" name="county_id" multiple="" tabindex="-1"     class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1">Adams</option>
<option value="2">Ashland</option>
<option value="3">Barron</option>
```

But when I select an item in the list, a blank box (the first, blank option) is shown as the first selection, right before the item I've selected. Note the first list item below:

```
<span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">
<ul class="select2-selection__rendered">
<span class="select2-selection__clear">×</span>
<li class="select2-selection__choice" title=""><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span></li>
<li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Kenosha"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Kenosha</li>
```

If I don't prepend the list with the blank option, then the placeholder does not work and the first list item is selected by default.

The closest example on the select2 site uses option groups (my list does not), and does not appear to have a blank option. I don't recall running into this issue with v3.5x.  I don't have any options set except placeholder. What could I be doing wrong? How can I get rid of this extra blank selection?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) by any chance? I had this issue using Formtastic. If not, maybe this can help lead you into the right direction anyway. I had to pass `:include_blank => false` into my form to remove the blank element. The [docs](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/wiki/4.1-Options-Cheat-Sheet) said `:prompt – by default, all select inputs will have a blank option at the top of the list. You can add a prompt with the :prompt option, or disable the blank option with :include_blank => false.` Maybe it is something similar to this?